# how to save the min num in an array ? assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

My goal is to sort the numbers in the given array from the lowest to the highest ( minloc, 01,06,07, '$'). I think the problem is in the min proc. as it always turns out to be 7 for some reason.
I have to use the base pointer and the procs should stay separated.
If you find the main cause of the bug and/or have a way to make my code better feel free to comment

```
DATASEG
minloc db ?
array db 6,7,1, '$'
CODESEG
proc min
   push bp
   mov bp,sp
   push bx di si
   found:
   mov si, bx ;start positions
   mov di , [bx]
   looparray:
   inc bx
   cmp [byte ptr bx], '$'
   je endofarray
   cmp [bx],di ;if [bx]< min value
   jb found
   jmp looparray
   endofarray:
   mov di, [bp+4]
   mov [di], si
   pop si di bx
   pop bp
   ret 4
endp min

proc swap
push bp 
mov bp,sp
push bx di dx ax
mov bx, [bp+6]
mov si, [bp+4]
mov ax, [bx]
mov dx, [si]
mov [bx], dx
mov [si], ax
pop ax dx di bx
pop bp
ret 6
endp swap

start:
   mov ax, @data
   mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
mov bx, offset array
arrayloop:
push offset min
call min
push [word ptr minloc]; bp+6
push bx ;bp+4
call swap
inc bx
cmp [byte ptr bx], '$'
jne arrayloop
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `push offset min` before `call min`?

Comment: i save in min the location of the cell with the smallest number / the push is to insert it to. every time i need it to update value

Comment: `min` is the name of the function you're calling. `minloc` is the place where you save the value, isn't it? So this would be an error.